# How to override toString() of final class in java

Tags: java

While profiling my java program through YourKit, yourkit reported me where the problem is;

[image]

Although my program is small and I can find out the place where problem is but I want to override toString() of Integer. So that yourkit can print it.

how can I do this?

*I have some ways to do it. Like if I on allocation monitor of yourkit profiler, or i just call toString() when i initialize an object. So I can match it with yourkit report. But I am looking for some good solution.

Comment: Is `abcdefg` what it really said, or is that something you just made up?  Please post the complete, real error message.

Comment: You cannot override any method of any final class.

Comment: As others have said, final classes cannot be overridden by definition.  However, `Integer.toString()` does not output what you show -- it outputs the integer value as a string.

Comment: I haven't used YourKit so maybe I'm misunderstanding, but what does it mean for a single `Integer` instance to be "the problem" in a profiler?  `Integer` is immutable so it's not like your program is wasting time repeatedly modifying it; once it's created, it just sits there in memory.

Comment: I have updated an image to elaborate my problem.

Comment: This is interesting because if just the method were `final` in _might_ be possible to use `setAccessible` to allow it to be overridden at runtime.  But as far as I'm aware, there is no `setAccessible` equivalent for `Class` objects.

Comment: I'd say the integer isn't the problem, the problem is that a class that's apparently intended to demonstrate deadlock has caused a deadlock.  :-)  It's likely that the integer is meaningless, just an arbitrary object to synchronize on.

Comment: @Wyzard, I created deadlock myself. So I know the cause. But I was looking some way. So I can ask junior to follow the way which can helps me to find out hot spot in their length programs.

Answer (score 2):

From Java Specification

[Chapter.8 Classes - final classes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.1.1.2)

final Classes

- **Because a final class never has any subclasses, the methods of a final class are never overridden**

And Integer is a final class

```
public final class Integer extends Number implements Comparable<Integer>
```

So you are not allow to override anything inside `Integer`.

However, Integer has already overridden `toString()` method which will display the number.

```
public String toString() {
    return String.valueOf(value);
}
```

So I believe there is probably something to do with how Yourkit display Java objects

Comment: 1+ for jls reference.

Answer (score 1):

YourKit might allow you to customize its output, but there is no way for you to override public final methods in Java proper, especially for core API classes such as java.lang.Integer.

Answer (score 0):

The Integer class is final. Therefore, you cannot overload it as you can only overload a method through making a class which inherits from the parent.

see http://www.roseindia.net/javatutorials/final_methods.shtml